# How to disable authentication during the start up of a Blazor B2C application?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side, asp.net5

I created a **ASP.NET 5 Blazor Server App** with **B2C Login**. The following is the start-up code. I see a **B2C** login page coming up when I run the application. How can I prevent the authentication during the startup? I want the user to login by clicking the **Login** link only from the top menu.

```
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));

            services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
                options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
            });

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();

            services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code and it looks like `options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;` is causing the automated redirect. Comment that out and give it a try, it should work. I also created a ASP .NET Core 5 Blazor Server app and tested this piece of code. After commenting the line mentioned above, I do get the LogIn Button available for the user to click on it.

```
services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
                //options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
            });
```

Comment: The solution did not work. The app is still getting redirected to the B2C login page. Please note that my application is a Blazor server application created with ASP.NET Core 5.

Comment: Updated the above comment, Please try that out and let us know if that works.